# call a function by clicking on a dynamically-inserted link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view that has a link in jquery, by clicking this link it calls a JavaScript function. I am not sure how to call the function and pass a parameter to the function.

this is the link:

```
var cell5 = $('<td />').html('<a href="functioncall?FileName=' + 
e.Application_Filename + '&RemoteRefNumber=' + e.RemoteRefNumber + '&target="_blank">PDF</a>');
```

and this is the function I would like to call.

```
 function getpdf(FileName,RemoteRefNumber) {
     [...]
 }
```

Comment: onClick="yourFunction()"

Comment: @Mark thank you can you be more specific,  I like to keep the line above starting cell5 where I can have onclick?

Comment: html('<a onCLick = "getpdf('+e.Application_Filename+','+...+')" href="..."  ...>PDF</a>')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wire this up inline via `onclick`, passing in your parameters. I **assume** you want to open a new browser window with some query params - observe the following...

```
 var cell5 = $('<td />').html('<a href="#" onclick="getpdf(\'' + e.Application_Filename + '\', \''  + e.RemoteRefNumber + '\');">PDF</a>');
```

---

```
window.getpdf = function(FileName, RemoteRefNumber) {

    // do you need to do anything else here?
    window.open('https://[...]?FileName=' + FileName + '&RemoteRefNumber=' + RemoteRefNumber);
}
```

Depending on what you're doing, why not just `href` it? Do you need to get into that function first? If not, this should suffice...

```
var cell5 = $('<td />').html('<a target="_blank" href="https://[...]?FileName=' + e.Application_Filename + '&RemoteRefNumber=' + e.RemoteRefNumber + '">PDF</a>')
```

note - in the first suggestion, I defined my function globally on `window`. Elsewise, that function is not available inline. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rt0dxfuk/) for a demonstration between three different function declarations and the behavior

Comment: excellent you are welcome. If you would't mind, can you let me know if the first suggestion worked or there was an error? If there is an issue I'd like to correct it

Comment: no the first suggestion wasn't working, it didn't happen anything after clicking on the link.

Comment: @Alma I have edited my answer out of curiosity if you are wondering why the first suggestion was not working. Apparently, we'd need to make `getpdf` as a globally available function. However, the `href` suggestion is ideal anyways, so you should be all set :)

Comment: We also had to add some escaped single quotes in there as well `\'`